# Is identifierForVendor different between development and distribution versions?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm working on an update for one of my games. I had a version that I downloaded from the app store on my device, and I pressed Run in xcode... The app got updated, but I had a little scare when I noticed that the game's stats all disappeared.

Now, after looking over my code, my only theory that makes any sense is that identifierForVendor is different. I use this as part of the key to encrypt my game's data (to make it impossible to just copy data between users). If it changes, it makes perfect sense that the data is lost.

So before submitting my update, I wanted to verify that this is the case - does identifierForVendor change between development versions and distribution versions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer - in the documentation, of all places :)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor

> Normally, the vendor is determined by data provided by the App Store. If the app was not installed from the app store (such as enterprise apps and apps still in development), then a vendor identifier is calculated based on the app’s bundle ID. The bundle ID is assumed to be in reverse-DNS format.

So the answer is "yes".